# Filter table for abundance in at least 20 % of the samples

Tags: awk, grep, tabular

I have a huge table tab separated like the one below: 
the first row is the subject list while the other rows are my counts.

```
KEGGAnnotation a b c d e f g h i l m n o p q r s t u v z w ee wr ty yu im
K01824 0 0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
K03924 17302 15372 19601 18732 17180 18094 23560 20516 14280 24187 19642 20521 20330 20843 22948 17124 19557 18319 16608 19463 18334 21022 14325 10819 13342 16876 16979
K13730 0 0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
K13735 5360 463 12516 7235 5051 2022 2499 2778 5392 1220 6460 9490 1169 6556 14862 9657 7360 6837 7810 4368 2186 12474 7810 9755 1401 12867 4431
K07279 0 0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
K14194 4499 2216 2322 2031 2763 2219 704 1647 2536 876 2692 4196 687 2958 3207 2153 2266 1974 370 2867 1110 5372 3637 9828 2038 2812 3472
K11494 0 0 1 10 0 0 0 0 11 0 0 0 0 0 14 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
K03332 0 0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
K01317 3 1 6 0 1 3 0 14 11 0 21 8 0 20 0 263 0 0 6 3 5 0 0 41 0 0 2
```

I would like to grep only the lines in which the counts >100 are present in at least 20% of the samples (= in at least 6 samples).

EX. sample Ko3924 will be grepped but not K03332.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Counts >=100 would be easy. Hint: numbers >=100 consist of at least 3 consecutive digits.

Comment: Just use awk, split every line on spaces and count how many entries are greater than 100. If more than 20%, print the line. This requires 8 lines at most.

Comment: Scale back your example to reduce the sample input to fewer fields on each line, there's no reason we need to be trying to read 30 fields per line just to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

increment the counter for values greater than the threshold.  Print the lines if the counter is greater than the 20% of the fields checked.  This will also print the header line.

```
awk '{c=0; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) c+=($i>=100); if(c>=0.2*(NF-1)) print $0}' input
```

Comment: +1.  This will fail to print the header line when there are fewer then 20% of columns names lexicographically after 100 ( for example if all the subject headers were 1, 2, 3, 4, ... ).